# Tkinter Not Showing image in Label

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-label

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
win=tk.Tk()
class loadfileclass():
    filenamevar=''
    data=''
    try:
        filenamevar=tk.StringVar()
        fname=filenamevar.get()
        filenamevar.set("")
        mainfile=open(str(fname),"rb")
        data=mainfile.read()
        data=data.split("##########")
    except:
        pass

tk.Label(text='Filename: ').pack()
tk.Entry(textvariable=loadfileclass.filenamevar).pack()
tk.Button(text='Load',command=loadfileclass).pack()
data=loadfileclass.data
for i in data:
    def fun():
        global photo,data
        data.replace("##########","\n")
        fd=data.split("==========")
        photo=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file=fd[1])
        tk.Label(fd[0],image=photo).pack()
    fun()
win.mainloop()
```

The label wont show, not even the image or the text.

Ok here is the file content of the file whose name i typed in the input:

IMAGE

```
==========
(opened image in notepad and copy pasted it here)
##########
IMAGE
==========
(opened image in notepad and copy pasted it here again)
##########
```

how to fix it?

Comment: If you think that question is not a duplicate, then explain why answers in duplicate question don't apply to your problem. Don't just add phrase "not a duplicate" because that will not get your question reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic image reference problem. Try like this:

```
def fun():
    global photo,data
    data.replace("##########","\n")
    fd=data.split("==========")
    photo=tk.PhotoImage(file=fd[1])
    lbl = tk.Label(fd[0],image=photo)
    lbl.pack()
    lbl.img_ref = photo # keep the reference
```